# Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format

Tags: git, github

I'm getting the error, I tried many ways. Both from terminal and with VSCode Git bash. How can I solve it?

```bash
C:\Users\duygu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\ssh_keys>ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "duygucansev@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\duygu/.ssh/id_rsa): id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:    I'm getting the sha256 key
```

The key's randomart image is:

```bash
C:\Users\duygu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\ssh_keys>man 1 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "duygucansev@gmail.com"
'man' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What error? The one about `'man' is not recognized`? Just ignore it. Or explain what **exactly** you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you pasting the data in `id_rsa` or `id_rsa.pub` on GitHub?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The random art would be useful for [someone wanting to validate your public key](https://superuser.com/a/22541/141).

But in your case (registering a new public key to your GitHub SSH settings), you don't need it.

Just do a `type C:\Users\duygu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, and copy the content of that file, as explained in "[Adding a new SSH key to your account](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account#adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-account)".